# Texmaker error "File not found" when using a "build" subdirectory for output files

Tags: errors, pdf, texmaker, ubuntu, viewers

I am using Texmaker in Ubuntu and have a file that worked when compiling using Quickbuild:

LaTeX + Bib(la)tex + LaTeX (x2) + dvips + ps2pdf + View PDF.

In order to tidy up my directory I picked the option "Use a "build" subdirectory for output files" and made all the changes in the different compiling commands (basically adding build/ in front of every %). However, the built-in viewer fails to find the PDF when I click "View PDF". External viewers work and "View DVI" and "View PS" work too, but I would like to see the PDF in the embedded viewer as I find it more comfortable.